# Как сверстать border, аналогичный комбинации fieldset и legend?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Как сверстать такой border?

[image]

Сайт на bootstrap, то есть он не должен сползать.
Сейчас сверстан с помощью legend и fieldset, что не поддерживается в ie8 и ранних версиях opera.
http://v.testjay.esy.es/

Answer (score 4):

Можно так http://jsfiddle.net/rpmv8u9k/ - заголовок абсолютом сделан, минус в том, что заголовок если увеличиться, он не двигает текст.

Или так http://jsfiddle.net/vnLw754b/ - заголовок через отрицательный margin, текст двигает, но позиционирование линий зависит от размера падинга у div, если он изменился нужно менять и отрицательный left/right у линий. Хотя это не проблема, можно падинг не указывать для div, а указать только для текста внутри.

Если заголовок не меняется, то подойдут оба варианта, если меняется, то второй.